# Clone android source repository and sync periodically from original source

Tags: android, git

I want to modify android source code and maintain the changes with my hosting provider. What is the best way to do the following.

1. Copy android source to a private hosting server (eg: githut, codesion).
2. Modify android changes and commit to the server that I hosted
3. Get latest updates from android git server and update those changes in my source tree

Answer (score 0):

Clone the public repo from GitHub. Push to a private repo on bitbucket. Depending on how many changes you will be making, you can rebase your changes on top of the mainline whenever there is a release.